# More lines for customer pole display

Tags: java

I am looking for pointers on where I can change the number of lines on a PoS display in unicenta opos.

I managed to figure out how to stop it from sending ESC data so I can show it on a 20x4 LCD hooked up to an arduino but can't figure out how to get it to accept 4 lines instead of the standard two.

So it uses top line and line 3. 2 and 4 stay blank.

```
display.write(trans.transString(DeviceTicket.alignLeft(m_displaylines.getLine1(), 20)));
display.write(trans.transString(DeviceTicket.alignLeft(m_displaylines.getLine2(), 20)));
```

This is the standard in .java file and works.

```
display.write(trans.transString(DeviceTicket.alignLeft(m_displaylines.getLine3(), 20)));
display.write(trans.transString(DeviceTicket.alignLeft(m_displaylines.getLine4(), 20)));
```

These that I want to add give me headache and need to figure out where it gets the data from.

Entire original code can be found here: [DeviceDisplaySurePOS.java](https://github.com/micolous/Openbravo/blob/master/src-pos/com/openbravo/pos/printer/escpos/DeviceDisplaySurePOS.java)